# How to determine if an item in a list begins with a certain character? (Python)

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to iterate through a list in python, and determine if any of the items in the list begins with the character `"a"`. However, my code seems to only check the first item in the list and doesn't iterate through the rest.

```
def isA(myList):
for i in range(len(myList)):
    if myList[i][0] == "a":
        print "True"
        return True
    else:
        print "False"
        return False
```

For example `isA(["acorn", "baseball"])` would return `True`, but `isA(["baseball", "acorn"]` returns `False`, when it should return `True` because there is an item in the list that begins with `a`.

Comment: Don't return False until you have walked the entire list.

Comment: `return any(ele[0] == "a" for ele in myList)`, that is a lot shorter and short circuits for the right reason ;)

Answer (score 5):

You have a `return` in the `if` block, and a `return` in the `else` block. So no matter how the condition evaluates, you will absolutely hit a `return` and the function will immediately terminate, having iterated no more than once.

If you want to check whether *any* item begins with "a", don't return as soon as you find an item that doesn't start with "a". Move that `return` to the end of the function.

```
def isA(myList):
    for i in range(len(myList)):
        if myList[i][0] == "a":
            return True
    return False
```

Alternatively, skip writing the function altogether and use the built-in function `any`.

```
>>> any(s.startswith("a") for s in ["baseball", "acorn"])
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `any()` function:

```
def isA(mylist):
    if any(l.startswith("a") for l in mylist):
        print "True"
        return True
    else:
        print "False"
        return False
```